# Returning array of objects from SOAP to PHP produces additional stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, soap, wsdl

Though I found many similar topics, I still could not solve my issue.

I am making a public SOAP service. It must return an object and one of it's values is an array of objects (e-shop order with a list of bought articles).

When I make a SOAP request using PHP SoapClient with no special settings, I receive an order, but it's articles are wrapped by one additional stdClass:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
  ["order_id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["client_id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["articles"]=>
   object(stdClass)#2 (1) {    <-- I want to eliminate
    ["article"]=>              <-- these lines
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
        ["article_id"] => string(1) "2"
        ["quantity"] => string(1) "8"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
        ["article_id"] => string(1) "4"
        ["quantity"]=> string(3) "1.5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The original object is:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'order_id' => '1',
   'client_id' => 1,
   'articles' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'article_id' => '2',
           'quantity' => 8,
        )),
        1 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'article_id' => '4',
           'quantity' => 1.5,
        ))
      )
    )
)
```

WSDL is:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:element name="article">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="article_id" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:decimal"></xs:element>
                </xs:all>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:complexType name="articles">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:article[]" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:element name="order">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="order_id" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="client_id" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="articles" type="articles"></xs:element>
                </xs:all>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="getOrderRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="id" type="xs:int" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getOrderResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="order" element="tns:order" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="orders">
    <wsdl:operation name="getOrder">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getOrderRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getOrderResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

SOAP response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:getOrderResponse>
            <order>
                <order_id>1</order_id>
                <client_id>1</client_id>
                <articles>
                    <article>
                        <article_id>2</article_id>
                        <quantity>8</quantity>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <article_id>4</article_id>
                        <quantity>1.5</quantity>
                    </article>
                </articles>
            </order>
        </SOAP-ENV:getOrderResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Though formally I can make something like `$order->articles = $order->articles->article;`, it is not good, because it will be a public service and I want to provide customers with a code example that will parse the result correctly.

What should be changed in WSDL or PHP Soap client to solve this issue?

Comment: I'd say drop your `articles` definition from your wsdl, and replace the reference to it in `order` with `<xs:element name="articles" type="article" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>` (and adjust code behind it that serves up those articles accordingly)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What do you think, how will this update influence SOAP clients in other languages (like Java or .Net)?

Comment: And immediately one more idea. If some order has several articles, resulting object will have member 'articles' as array of objects. But if order has only one article, 'articles' will be just an object. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You're changing your WSDL, every client is effected, no matter the implementation. You've got a point with single items not be an array, you could set the `srticle` in a `sequence` & enable `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` to overcome that.

Comment: Wrikken, thank you very much for your help! I tried to use feature SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, but there was no difference. IMHO, it seams that SOAP and WSDL are loosing their popularity. PHP implementation of SOAP is poorly documented, W3C has no same good WSDL validator as http://validator.w3.org, other validators give different results, most developments are about 6 years old. It is subjective, but finally I have change my service to use REST.

Comment: That `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` indeed only works if you use it in tandem with a `xsd:sequence`. But you're right SOAP is overkill for a lot of applications. Do keep in mind that `REST` doesn't exclude a proper XSD if you're supporting XML, and as a developer, I like verifiable REST interfaces like that more then JSON, for which less grown-up schema validation tools exist.